View available and insert diacritic characters via an interactive menu on macOS?
Long-pressing a key on iOS brings up a menu of diacritics for that character:
Long-pressing 'u' on iOS:

Long-pressing 'a' on iOS:

Question
How can a similar menu be made to appear on macOS?
Note
A diacritic of choice can be inserted directly but it doesn't provide a menu and requires memorising each diacritic character and its keybinding - a menu to select from (as on iOS) would avoid having to memorise or look up specific keybindings.

When I long press a key I get a popup menu as shown, tested on macOS 14.6.1 and 12.6.7:

(Apple first incorporated this feature in OS X 10.7 Lion)

The menu looks perfect. Do you have to disable key repeat to make this work? (when I hold a key it repeats that key)

I suspect that the two are mutually exclusive.

If there's a way to have both this would be the perfect solution. Not sure if it's possible. option + letter makes the greek alphabet (I'm guessing here), and option + shift + letter makes some other characters. I wonder if some other key combo + letter could be made to allow longpress to bring up this diacritics menu

If you don’t also see the accent menu popup in macOS, something is messed up.  For the fix, see
https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250006751

Thanks. I don't want to reboot atm but will try very next opportunity and report back. From the answer given, it sounds like we can have our cake and eat it too (have key repeat on whilst having longpress also bring up the diacritics menu)

@stevec Sorry, no key repeat on letters, just symbols.  For letters it is one or the other.

Interesting. I thought from this bit of the linked answer "make sure that Key Repeat is NOT set to Off and that  Delay Until Repeat is not set too long" it sounds like both (key repeat and accent menu) are on

@stevec key repat off means no keys repeat and no accent menus.  Key repeat on means symbols repeat and letters have the accent menu.  I think symbols includes @#$&()’l%-+=/;:,.€£$_(]{}§|~…<>!?  but I have not tested them all.
